# If I buy a code signing certificate how many applications could I sign with it?

Tags: c#, windows, certificate, digital-certificate

I plan to buy code signing for my application. I see couple of hundreds dollar cost a key. But if I buy it I could only use to sign one application, or I could use it as much as I want?

I want sign my two C# applications and my NSIS installer.

Comment: You should edit the question instead of commenting on it, if the new information is crucial for answering it.

Comment: It's *sign*, not *sing*.

Comment: You can sign as many things with it as you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sign as much as you want, within the time range, the certificate is valid (most of the time one or two years).

Please make sure that you buy the right certificate for your task! For example you need *other* certificates for signing Windows Kernel Drivers than for signing normal applications.